# Anybody know why I have no other selection but blank solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and trying to use c# for unity.
I installed the unity package but still, I see nothing but a blank solution. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Did you select anything to install? there is nothing pre-selected, and you have to choose what components you like eg. for gaming, for web, for desktop

Answer (score 0):

you must add this option in the installation:

[image]

Comment: it's checked but it shows me the same thing

Answer (score 0):

We can see that“Projects are created using the Unity Editor and not Visual Studio”.

[image]

If you want to solve your problem, you can refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows)